# Flash input text-field sent to email using PHP

Tags: php, forms, flash, email, actionscript-2

I'm creating a form in Flash CS6 - Actionscript 2 & Flash Player 8. I'd like to send an email with the input-data using PHP.

I have an input text-field with an instance name of *nInput* and a button: *bSubmit*.

**My button in Flash:**

```
 bSubmit.onRelease = function()
 {
  email();
 }
 function email()
 {
  var sMessage = "This is from a form<br/><br/>" + "Number: " + nInput.text;
  lvSend = new LoadVars();
  lvReply = new LoadVars();
  lvSend.msg = sMessage;
  lvSend.address = "my@email.com"; 
  nInput.text = "";

  lvSend.sendAndLoad('mail.php', lvReply, 'POST');
}
```

**My PHP-script**

```
<?php
$message = stripslashes($_POST['msg']);
$address = $_POST["address"];
$headers = "From:another@email.com \r\n";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
mail($address,"My Subject",$message, $headers);
?>
```

Everything works well, except the input-data isnt showing. This is how the email looks like:

*This is from a form*

*Number: undefined*

I guess there's something wrong with the script in Flash, but I can't figure out what. Do you guys know? Thanks.

**EDIT**

This works:

```
bSubmit.onRelease = function()
{
    email();
}
function email()
{
    var nInput = nInput.text;
    var sMessage = "This is from a form<br/><br/>" + "Number: " + nInput;
    lvSend = new LoadVars();
    lvReply = new LoadVars();
    lvSend.msg = sMessage;
    lvSend.address = "my@email.com"; 


    lvSend.sendAndLoad('mail.php', lvReply, 'POST');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Glad you got it working. Just for future reference you can do

```
bSubmit.onRelease = email;
```

Instead of putting:

```
function() {
  email();
}
```

Unless you wanted to pass parameters in which case that would make sense as such:

```
bSubmit.onRelease = function() {
    email(nInput.text, "my@address.com");
}
```